# Hide all series button in CanvasJS graph (javascript foreach usage)

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvasjs

The question related to CanvasJS, but probably any expert in pure javascript could help.

I need a button to hide/unhide all elements in canvasjs graph.
There is a working code that can hide element using array index:

```
chart.options.data[0].visible = !chart.options.data[0].visible;
```

I'm trying to go through array, but it doesn't work, obviously my code is wrong:

```
chart.options.data.forEach(visible = !visible);
```

How should I fix it?

The full code snippet is:

```js
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
      text: "Test Button to Hide All Series"  
      },
      
      legend: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            itemclick: function (e) {
                //console.log("legend click: " + e.dataPointIndex);
                //console.log(e);
                if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                } else {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                }
 
                e.chart.render();
            }
        },
      
      data: [
      { 
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 5 },
        { x: 20, y: 9},
        { x: 30, y: 17 },
        { x: 40, y: 32 },
        { x: 50, y: 22 },
        { x: 60, y: 14 },
        { x: 70, y: 25 },
        { x: 80, y: 18 },
        { x: 90, y: 20}
      
        ]
      },
        {
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 31 },
        { x: 20, y: 35},
        { x: 30, y: 30 },
        { x: 40, y: 35 },
        { x: 50, y: 35 },
        { x: 60, y: 38 },
        { x: 70, y: 38 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 44}
      
        ]
      },
        {
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 25 },
        { x: 20, y: 30},
        { x: 30, y: 20 },
        { x: 40, y: 45 },
        { x: 50, y: 30 },
        { x: 60, y: 10 },
        { x: 70, y: 15 },
        { x: 80, y: 18 },
        { x: 90, y: 20}
      
        ]
      }
      ]
    });
 
    chart.render();
    
 document.getElementById("showAllSeries").onclick =  function(){
   //Works for a single element using index:
   chart.options.data[0].visible = !chart.options.data[0].visible;
   //Doesn't work, need to modify
   //chart.options.data.forEach(visible = !visible);
   chart.render();
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<center><button id= "showAllSeries" style= "margin: 10px;">Show/Hide All series</button></center>
```

**UP:**
Found solution with for loop:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < chart.options.data.length; i++) {
   chart.options.data[i].visible = !chart.options.data[i].visible;
   }
```

But still interesting how should it work with *foreach*

Comment: `forEach` is just syntactic sugar for the `for` line, so just take what's between the curly brackets for your `for` loop, put it in the `forEach` function, and replace `chart.options.data[i]` with the first argument to the function passed to `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forEach is an Array method that you can use to execute a function on each element in an array. On the other hand for is a loop that is more flexible.

In your case, you can hide all dataSeries onclick of button either using for or forEach. Check the code below:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 title:{
  text: "Test Button to Hide All Series"  
 },

 legend: {
  cursor: "pointer",
  itemclick: function (e) {
   if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
   } else {
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
   }
   e.chart.render();
  }
 },

 data: [
  { 
  showInLegend: true,
  type: "line",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 10, y: 5 },
   { x: 20, y: 9 },
   { x: 30, y: 17 },
   { x: 40, y: 32 },
   { x: 50, y: 22 },
   { x: 60, y: 14 },
   { x: 70, y: 25 },
   { x: 80, y: 18 },
   { x: 90, y: 20 }
  ]
  },
  {
  showInLegend: true,
  type: "line",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 10, y: 31 },
   { x: 20, y: 35 },
   { x: 30, y: 30 },
   { x: 40, y: 35 },
   { x: 50, y: 35 },
   { x: 60, y: 38 },
   { x: 70, y: 38 },
   { x: 80, y: 34 },
   { x: 90, y: 44 }
  ]
  },
  {
  showInLegend: true,
  type: "line",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 10, y: 25 },
   { x: 20, y: 30 },
   { x: 30, y: 20 },
   { x: 40, y: 45 },
   { x: 50, y: 30 },
   { x: 60, y: 10 },
   { x: 70, y: 15 },
   { x: 80, y: 18 },
   { x: 90, y: 20 }
  ]
  }
 ]
});

chart.render();

document.getElementById("showAllSeries").onclick =  function(){
 chart.options.data.forEach(function(dataSeries) {
   if (typeof (dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || dataSeries.visible) {
   dataSeries.visible = false;
  } else {
   dataSeries.visible = true;
  }
 });
 /*var dataSeries;
   for(var i = 0; i < chart.data.length; i++){
   dataSeries = chart.options.data[i];
  if (typeof (dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || dataSeries.visible) {
   dataSeries.visible = false;
  } else {
   dataSeries.visible = true;
  }
 }*/  
 chart.render();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
<center><button id= "showAllSeries" style= "margin: 10px;">Show/Hide All series</button></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vishwas for detailed answer. Generally - yes, both for & forEach are fine usable here. I will mark it as correct, but it helped me to get more concise solution using forEach that I expected:

```
document.getElementById(""showAllSeries"").onclick =  function(){
 chart.options.data.forEach(function(dataSeries) {
    dataSeries.visible = !dataSeries.visible })
    chart.render();
    };
```

Will leave it here for a history also:

```js
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
      text: "Test Button to Hide All Series"  
      },
      
      legend: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            itemclick: function (e) {
                //console.log("legend click: " + e.dataPointIndex);
                //console.log(e);
                if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                } else {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                }
 
                e.chart.render();
            }
        },
      
      data: [
      { 
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 5 },
        { x: 20, y: 9},
        { x: 30, y: 17 },
        { x: 40, y: 32 },
        { x: 50, y: 22 },
        { x: 60, y: 14 },
        { x: 70, y: 25 },
        { x: 80, y: 18 },
        { x: 90, y: 20}
      
        ]
      },
        {
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 31 },
        { x: 20, y: 35},
        { x: 30, y: 30 },
        { x: 40, y: 35 },
        { x: 50, y: 35 },
        { x: 60, y: 38 },
        { x: 70, y: 38 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 44}
      
        ]
      },
        {
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 25 },
        { x: 20, y: 30},
        { x: 30, y: 20 },
        { x: 40, y: 45 },
        { x: 50, y: 30 },
        { x: 60, y: 10 },
        { x: 70, y: 15 },
        { x: 80, y: 18 },
        { x: 90, y: 20}
      
        ]
      }
      ]
    });
 
    chart.render();
    
    document.getElementById("showAllSeries").onclick=function(){
      chart.options.data.forEach(function(dataSeries){
  dataSeries.visible = !dataSeries.visible
            })
     chart.render();
     };
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<center><button id= "showAllSeries" style= "margin: 10px;">Show/Hide All series</button></center>
```

Comment: If you use `dataSeries.visible = !dataSeries.visible`, it won't hide all the dataSeries in first click as visible property is undefined initially. However it starts working fine after 2nd click. Thats the reason I had used `if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                } else {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                }`

Comment: Really, the first click doesn't work here and on jsfiddle, but it works if I make the same code in html page and then open it in any browser. Anyway, your option is more reliable of course.